# Get value from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have database fragment like this:

```
{
  "users": {
    "usersCount": {
      "count": 61
     ...
     ...
    }
  }
}
```

I want to assign a value to a variable like this:

```
var count = getUserCount();
```

From this function:

```
function getUsersCount() {
    const ref = db.ref('users/usersCount');
    ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
        console.log("Value is: ", snapshot.val().count); // There value is right
        return snapshot.val().count;
    }, function (errorObject) {
        console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
    });
}
```

But whatever I try, the function returns undefinde or object promise

Comment: there is no option to help you when you do not mention which db framework are you using and in which version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since once() is asynchronous, its not possible to make getUsersCount return a value synchronously.  It will have to return a promise that resolves to the value that you want the caller to have.  It should look like this:

```
function getUsersCount() {
    const ref = db.ref('users/usersCount');
    return ref.once("value")
    .then(snapshot => {
        console.log("Value is: ", snapshot.val().count); // There value is right
        return snapshot.val().count;
    })
}
```

And the caller uses the returned promise like this:

```
getUsersCount()
.then(count => {
    console.log("Count", count);
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log("The read failed", error);
})
```

Comment: Thx, for help bro. You are awesome! ;)